# Installing GDAL in Anaconda on an offline machine

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, offline, gdal

I have an offline windows machine with anaconda 2021.5, and I want to install GDAL on it. I am able to install it onto my online computer, but i get multiple conflicts when installing it on my offline computer

I have tried installing it on my online computer through anaconda prompt:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

This works well on my online computer.

Then i create a requirements.txt file, and dump all the required packages into a custom anaconda channel on my offline computer. Then i create a new and empty env, and install the packages with this command:

```
conda create --name gdal -c file:///D:\path\to\custom\channel --file C:\path\to\requirements.txt
```

The command finds all the required packages, but it fails with a load of conflicts. Almost every package is in conflict with each other.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this myself by installing the packages one by one

It seems like a few packages weren't compatible with my installation of anaconda. So i just skipped those and did

```
conda install D:/path/to/package.bz2
```

on the other packages.